# Service call failed in WCF through c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simple client and server file but service call fails, and I don't know why. Also, I am not able to find the contract name in the dll file.

Client :

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/SelfHostedServiceConsole"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService1"
          contract="SelfHostedService.ISampleService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am calling using runclient.cmd:

```
set local
TestClient admin
pause
```

Every time I run this I just get

> Using self hosted service
>   Service call failed

Client code:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="localhost/SelfHostedServiceConsole"; binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService1&‌​quot; contract="SelfHostedService.ISampleService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService1" />
</client>
```

Comment: Client code : <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/SelfHostedServiceConsole"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService1"
                contract="SelfHostedService.ISampleService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService1" />
        </client>

Comment: Are you sure the `&quot;` belongs there? shouldn't it be a `"`. There are also a lot of strange `;` in your client configuration